# Increment variable name

Tags: sas

Is it possible to increment different prefixed variable names in a simple way? For example, if my dataset has columns for Score1 all the way to Score20, I can simply do:

```
input Score1-Score20;
```

But what if I have Score1 Rank1 Total1 to Score20 Rank20 Total20, is there a way to increment these without manually typing out each one? So the result would look like:

```
Score1 Rank1 Total1 Score2 Rank2 Total2 Score3 Rank3 Total3 etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you care if the variables are created in a different order than in the input file?  If not then use an ARRAY. Try this example.

```
data x ;
  array x(3,20) a1-a20 b1-b20 c1-c20 ;
  infile cards truncover;
  do block=1 to 20;
   do item=1 to 3; 
     input  x(item,block) @; 
   end; 
  end; 
  put (_all_) (=);
  list;
cards;
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
;
```

If you need them in that order then you need to use some type of code generation.

You could create a simple function style macro to emit the list of names.

```
%macro namelist(baselist,n);
%local i j;
%do i=1 %to &n ;
%do j=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&baselist));
  %scan(&baselist,&j)&i
%end;
%end;
%mend namelist;
...
input %namelist(Rank Total Score,20) ;
```

Or you could use a simple data step to build the list into a macro variable.

```
data _null_;
  length i 8 basename $30 namelist $32000;
  do i=1 to 20 ;
    do basename='Rank ','Total','Score';
       namelist=catx(' ',namelist,cats(basename,i));
    end;
  end;
  call symputx('namelist',namelist);
run;
...
input &namelist ;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if there's an easy way to create the variables in that order

Comment: Nice answer Tom. In your %namelist definition, I think you want the second parameter to be n.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do a macro for this.  I think this would work:

```
%macro mymacro(runs);
   %do i=1 %to &runs;
         input Score&i Rank&i Total&i;
      run;
   %end;
%mend create;
%mymacro(20)
```

Try here for better documentation: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543755.htm

Comment: That wouldn't work, unless there were a line break between each set - you'd need to use @ or construct your macro differently (not including the input statement, for example, and just creating the variable list).

Comment: Yea, this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. It seems like a could be a good place to start though

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked here earlier in the week, the answer is the same.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Variables-listing/m-p/238350#M34601

You could create a macro to create the names.

```
data _null_;
length var $1000.;

do i=1 to 10;

   var=catt(var, " Total"||put(i, 2. -l), " Male"||put(i, 2. -l), " Female"||put(i, 2. -l));
 end;

 call symputx('input_list', var);
 run;

%put &input_list;
```